# The OOM killer kills processes, even if there is enough memory available

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, systemd

While running an application on sles12 sp2 (which has 4.4.21 Linux kernel) I observed that the OOM killer killed my application. But at that time the available main memory was nearly 2GB out of 15GB and swap space was 6GB.  I tried to understand the OOM killer kernel code. If I understood code correctly,  in the above situation the OOM killer should not be invoked.

What could be the reason to invoke the OOM killer?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-the-oom-killer-decides-which-process-to-kill-first
I think this may help you lot,Here they explained very well.

Comment: For example that may be caused by high-order allocations while your memory is fragmented heavily